# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sin'?

Tags: python, numpy

Below is my short code, but it has an error:  `"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sin'"`.
 I don't understand why and how to fix.
Please guide me!

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
import numpy as np
w1 = 0.3
w2 = 0.2
w0 = 0.4

x1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)

A = np.array([1,X,Y],dtype=object)
w = np.array([[w0],[w1],[w2]])
Z = np.sin(A.dot(w))
print (Z)
```

Comment: You probably want `np.sin(A.dot(w)[0])`

Comment: You can use `np.sin` with numeric arrays only (look at the `.dtype` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Because you define `A` with `dtype=object`, the result of `A.dot(w)` will be of type object as well. As a consequence of this, `numpy.sin` tries to call `sin` as a member function of the elements in the result of `A.dot(w)` which is not defined.

Produces error: `np.sin(np.array([np.array(1)], dtype=object))`
No error: `np.sin(np.array([np.array(1)]))`

As @Adelin has mentioned above, simply call `np.sin(A.dot(w)[0]`.

Comment: Thanks all so much. I found my mistake, that is "w". In the case, w = np.array([w0, w1, w2]), not w = np.array([[w0],[w1],[w2]])   :)